# How can I change the admin username in phpVirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, php

I am using [phpVirtualBox](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpvirtualbox/).

The default setup adds a user with username: `admin` and password: `admin`.

I can change the password, but can't seem to change the username.

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As admin, add a new user with admin status.

Log out, and log back in, then delete user `admin`.